# How to customize list page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-list

I am creating a new custom module in Magento 2. I want to add new custom text on listing page. I've attached a screenshot for reference.

Create a **`di.xml`** file in a folder `Magenticians/Mymodule/etc`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Magenticians\Mymodule\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

The next step to overriding Magento 2 block is to create a **`ListProduct.php`** block file in the folder `Magenticians/Mymodule/Block/Product`:

```
<?php
/**
* Rewrite Product ListProduct Block
* @category    FME
* @package     FME_Test
* @author      Fme Extensions Development Company
*/

namespace Magenticians\Mymodule\Block\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                echo "you can do this in block"; die();
            }
    }
```

Create **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** inside `app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magenticians_Mymodule::cart.phtml</argument>
    </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Now, create **`cart.phtml`** file at location `app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates`:

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
//write your stuff here
```

[image]

Please suggest me

Comment: Please add more information about your custom text. like you want to call that custom text from your module?

Comment: @Abhishek Panchal  I updated code

Comment: Why your code is showing 3 different namespace `FME\Test`  and `Magenticians/Mymodule`  and `Webkul_Hello`

Comment: @ Abhishek Panchal  I have update code

Comment: what's the purpose of `cart.phtml` ?

Comment: In cart.phtml  i am only add custom text for displaying on list page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69075/discussion-between-santosh-and-abhishek-panchal).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69129/discussion-between-santosh-and-abhishek-panchal).